# created new tag "makeindex"

Tags: discussion, tagging

After it became clear that [a recent question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301442/78282) was connected to issues with {makeindex} I tagged it with that tag name. Only after that I realized that I had thereby just created that tag. Before there was only a generic tag {indexing}. In the description it says

> {indexing} is about creating an index or similar lists for your
>   document, usually by means of executing makeindex.

However, there is an own tag {xindy}, for example. In my opinion, my tag choice makes sense for such a question since it is essentially not referring to how to create some sort of index but boils down to a setting of `makeindex`. I understand the {indexing} tag as more general. Is that valid?

Comment: I think, in this case it is justified. I assume, that there are more questions that have the [tag:makeindex] tag then.

Comment: I've just edited the tag info